# password not working help needed

Tags: javascript, passwords

I've been working on a password to protect my webpage which is kind of an experiment page as I'm new to html, css and java.

Below is the code for the password. Can someone help me? The password seems to count anything typed into the provided space as true. I need only one password to work but I'm not sure how to go about it. Below is the code of the password any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 <script>
    function checkPassword(){
    var password = document.getElementById("PasswordBox");
    var passwordText = password.value;
    if(passwordText == "pheasey101"){
    return true;

    alert("access denied! Incorrect password!!");
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: You do realise that anyone can read your password if it is sent to the browser in plain text. Press F12 and they can read your scripts!

Comment: Mike. I now realise this problem too. Ill have ti work on that but thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not too sure about javascript but in java when comparing two strings, you have to use .Equals() and not ==, for example, in java your code should be:

```
if(passwordText.Equals("pheasey101")) {
    return true;
}
```

another problem i notice you have is that you are missing a curly brace, after the if statement you open the curly brace but you never close it keeping the alert part and return false part in the if statement. that also means that the function doesn't have a definitive end. after the return true, add the closing curly brace and see if that fixes it otherwise try using .Equals if there is such a thing in javascript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nah, using '==' is fine in JavaScript. Using '===' is better.

Comment: Thanks fir the help

Answer (score 0):

Without all of your relevant code, it'll be difficult to tell, but I suspect you're running into JavaScript's truthy/falsey values. The lack of a closing brace, as pointed out earlier, means that your function probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. At the same time, the fact that everything returns true means you've probably got this somewhere else:

```
if (checkPassword){
    //the thing that always happens
}
```

...or this:

```
if (checkPassword()){
    //the thing that always happens
}
```

When you use implicit equality like above, JavaScript uses type coercion to evaluate true/false. Since your function 'checkPassword' doesn't appear to return a default value, JavaScript will check to see if it exists in memory as a reference, which will then evaluate as true.

```
if (checkPassword() == true){
    //a better sort of check, but it also uses type coercion
    //if checkPassword returns the string "true", this will pass
}

if (checkPassword() === true){
    //an even better check; no type coercion occurs
}
```

Fix your function so that it always returns a value, then use strict equality to evaulate that result.

Comment: Thanks for the help